# Any alternative for Apache Nutch?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, nutch

I'm looking for a solution like below:

1- search a given keyword in search engines (Google,Yahoo...)

2- receive results (links)

3- go to the links and extract contents and ...

After a brief research I found "Apache Nutch", I just want to know your suggestion.

**do you have any recommendation for this solution?**

**Is there any better solution for what I explained?**

I'm a python developer and I'm familiar with tools like "Scrapy".

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For step-by-step to build a search engine, visit http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes